# Dictionaries and Functions

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have recently begun working with C# and there is something I used to do easily in Python that I would like to achieve in C#.

For example, I have a function like:

```
def my_func():
 return "Do some awesome stuff"
```

And a dictionary like:

```
my_dic = {"do": my_func}
```

I have made a script in which when the user would input "do", the program would call `my_func` according to the dictionary.

I'd like to know how I can assign functions to strings in a C# dictionary.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi: No you don't. You just need delegates, like standard `Action` or `Func`. Or `Expression`s. Of course they all are internally based on reflection, since `MethodInfo` is somewhere inside of each of these, but it's nothing like finding/invoking it manually.

Comment: See also: [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173171.aspx) and especially the built in generic delegate types [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.action.aspx) (for methods with `void` return type) and [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534960.aspx) (for methods with non-`void` return type) and their many overloads.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Basically in the same way:

```
static void Main() {
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    // map "do" to MyFunc
    dict.Add("do", MyFunc);
    // run "do"
    dict["do"]();
}

static void MyFunc() {
    Console.WriteLine("Some stuff");
}
```

Comment: You can also do lambda expressions: `dict.Add("do", () => Console.WriteLine("Some stuff"));`. The key here is that `Action` is a delegate type, and it specifies that the function must take no parameters and return no result. There are other, generic versions of `Action` that allow for taking arguments, and `Func` allows for returning a value. Also worth noting that for this to work, all the functions need the same parameter set and type of output.

Comment: Unlike Python C# has multiline lambdas by the way: () => { Console.WriteLine("A"); Console.WriteLine("B"); }, since it is not limited by the "gut feeling" of its creator.

Comment: @Traubenfuchs To be fair to Python, you could do multiline functions in any scope via `def` long before (I believe) `lambda` was added to the language. So the limitation makes sense when you consider `lambda` to be a convenience for inlining very simple operations and the fact that multi-expression lambdas would probably either complicate parsing immensely or require a ton of syntax elements. By contrast, you certainly can't define normal functions (which are parts of classes) in a function scope with C#, so lambda functions fill more roles in C# than they do in Python.

Answer (score 19):

You can take advantage of the collection initializer syntax here.

```
var my_dic = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    { "do", my_func }
};
```

For more sophisticated functions, you'd replace `Action` in the declaration with the appropriate `Function` type.

Comment: For trivial cases you can also use lambda syntax in the collection initializer (and in some cases just write the name of the method group)

Answer (score 5):

The C# code fragments that would be most directly analogous to your examples are:

```
string my_func() {
  return "Do some awesome stuff";
}
```

And:

```
var my_dic = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>> {
  { "do", my_func },
};
```

The trick, as the other posters have pointed out, is to create a string whose generic value type is of either an Action (which is a method that returns void) or a Func<T> (which is a method that returns an object of type T).

In either case, you could then execute the method with:

```
var result = my_dic["do"]();
```

Comment: I added my answer, despite being very similar to Evk's and Adam E's answers, since neither of them provided direct code analogs of the example provided by Balgy.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want the dynamic behavior of Python (i.e. being able to seamlessly assign and call methods that have different signatures to a "dictionary"), I'd go with the ExpandoObject which was specifically meant to be able to have the CLR support dynamic languages such as Python (see IronPython, et al).

```
static void Main()
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    expando.Do = new Func<string>(MyFunc);
    expando.Do2 = new Func<string, string>(MyFunc2);

    Console.WriteLine(expando.Do());
    Console.WriteLine(expando.Do2("args"));
}

static string MyFunc()
{
    return "Do some awesome stuff";
}

static string MyFunc2(string arg)
{
    return "Do some awesome stuff with " + arg;
}
```

If you prefer, you can even treat an ExpandoObject as a dictionary:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>) expando;
    dict["Do"] = new Func<string>(MyFunc);
    dict["Do2"] = new Func<string, string>(MyFunc2);

    Console.WriteLine(expando.Do());
    Console.WriteLine(expando.Do2("args"));
}

static string MyFunc()
{
    return "Do some awesome stuff";
}

static string MyFunc2(string arg)
{
    return "Do some awesome stuff with " + arg;
}
```

** Edit **

Full disclosure: This question seems very similar (if not a dupe) of [String- Function dictionary c# where functions have different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992411/string-function-dictionary-c-sharp-where-functions-have-different-arguments/37123961#37123961), which I just answered the same way.